# for loop, trying to exclude numbers in the if and else statement

Tags: python

I am reletively new to python, as you can see if the 'n' is divisible by 5, 6 and 5&6 something happens but for those numbers it still shows (ex. 100O) when it is divisble by 5 or 6 i dont want the 'n' number to print. Any suggestions will help but please keep it at a novice level so i may learn.

```
def main():
    numHigh = 101
    for n in range(numHigh, 0, -1):
        print(n)
        if (n % 5 == 0):
            print("Where do you see yourself in five years?")
        elif (n % 6 == 0):
            print("I'll believe six impossible things before breakfast.")
        elif (n % 5 == 0) & (numHigh % 6 == 0):
            print("Thirty days in hath September.")
main()


Sample Output: 
101
100
Where do you see yourself in five years?
99
98
97
96
I'll believe six impossible things before breakfast.
95
Where do you see yourself in five years?
94
93


I want this output:
101
Where do you see yourself in five years?
99
98
97
96
I'll believe six impossible things before breakfast.
Where do you see yourself in five years?
94
93
```

Comment: Delete the `print(n)`. Create an `else:` after the last `elif ...` and put the `print(n)` in there

Comment: wow, i feel stupid, thank you so much it worked.

Comment: @AlfredH. Also, in the last elif, why do you have `numHigh % 6`? Shouldn't it be `n % 6`? `numHigh` always stays at 101 and so that condition will never be true.

Comment: Did you really want a bit-wise and (`&`)? Or do you really want a logical and (`and`)?

Comment: @Tur1ng, good catch I will fix that!!!

Comment: @SethMMorton, I wanted a logical and, what do you mean by bit wise?

Comment: @AlfredH. Actually, the last elif will never evaluate anyways, due to the structure of the conditions. For example, try `90` for input.

Comment: @Tur1ng, how would i get that last elif to work?

Comment: @Tur1ng, wouldnt i add a nested if statement under the first (n%5)

Comment: You could do it that way, or you can have the more specific check before the less specific one.

Comment: @AlfredH. Put the last `elif` as the first `if` condition. That basically says, first check to see if n is divisible by both 5 and 6. Otherwise (if it's not), check separately to see if n is divisible by 5 or 6. Edit: As @PatrickHaugh said.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def main():
numHigh = 101
for n in range(numHigh, 0, -1):
    if (n % 5 == 0):
        print("Where do you see yourself in five years?")
    elif (n % 6 == 0):
        print("I'll believe six impossible things before breakfast.")
    elif (n % 5 == 0) & (numHigh % 6 == 0):
        print("Thirty days in hath September.")
    else:
        print(n)
main()
```

Comment: Problem was solved in the comments by inspectorG4dget. If you are just posting the answer, maybe expand on it and explain on why it's happening or what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The print(n) is in the beginning of your for loop so it will print n every time the loop runs. Instead you should create an else statement after your ifs and elifs. That way if all those ifs/elifs aren't true it will print n.

Like this

```
if …
elif …
elif …
else:
    print(n)
```